# Vue 2 with typescript multiple types for the props

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, vuejs2

I have a simple prop in my Vue.js component in which I want to pass either a **boolean** or an **array**.

The problem is that when I do:

```js
props: {
  checked: {
    type: [Boolean, Array],
    default: false,
  },
},
```

I will have to face the problems an `unknow[]` array will give me.

And if I do something like this:

```js
props: {
  checked: {
    type: [Boolean, Array as PropType<string[] | number[]>],
    default: false,
  },
},
```

It will completely break my component. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help my bros.

Comment: That seems like a Vue bug. A workaround is to do: `type: Object as PropType<boolean | string[] | number[]>`. That downside to that is you lose runtime prop validation of `Boolean` during dev, but the TypeScript compiler errors should help.

Comment: @tony19 That worked. If you take the time to make an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a Vue bug.

A workaround is to do:

```js
props: {
  checked: {
    type: Object as PropType<boolean | string[] | number[]>,
  },
},
```

The downside to this is you lose runtime prop validation of `Boolean` during dev, but the TypeScript compiler would emit an error if you used an invalid type (something other than a `boolean`, `string[]`, or `number[]`).

Answer (score 0):

I think so " Boolean | Array ",It should not be an array

Comment: The `type` field of Vue props supports [multiple constructors in an array](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).